can't connect clients with server unix socket with select
I am studying sockets in C. I am trying to connect multiple client(n thread posix) to a collector process with sockets using select. I am following my professor example but I don't know why when I run I can't connect my threads to the server.
threads function:
void *workerFunction(void *arg) {
   int client_fd;
   char message[BUFFER_SIZE];
 
 //Creazione socket
 if((client_fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1){
   perror("Errore nelal creazione del socket");
   pthread_exit(NULL);
 }
 
 // Connessione al server
   while (connect(client_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == -1) {
   if(errno == ENOENT) sleep(1);
   else{
       printf("Errore nella connessione al server\n");
       close(client_fd);
       pthread_exit(NULL);
   }
 }
   
   workerList *currentWorker = (workerList *)arg;
   
 // Ciclo del thread, termina quando `terminateThread` diventa 1 o il worker deve terminare
 while (1) {
       char *fileName = takeFromQueue();
       
       if(fileName == NULL){
           break;
       }
       
       long result = readValueFromFile(fileName);
       snprintf(message, BUFFER_SIZE, "Thread %d, Il risultato del file %s: %ld\n", currentWorker->thId, fileName, result);
       
       if(write(client_fd, message, strlen(message)) == -1){
           perror("Errore nell'invio del messaggio");
       }
       
       free(fileName);  // Libera la memoria allocata per il fileName
   
   }
   close(client_fd);
   
   return NULL;
}

collector process:
void *collectorFunction() {
        setup_signal_handlers();
    int server_fd, client_fd, max_fd = 0, fd, nread;
    fd_set read_fds, active_fds;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

        // Impostazione dell'indirizzo
    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(server_addr.sun_path, SOCKET_PATH, sizeof(server_addr.sun_path) - 1);

    // Creazione socket
    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("Errore nella creazione del socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
        
        unlink(SOCKET_PATH);

    // Associazione socket
    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == -1) {
        perror("Errore nel bind del socket");
        close(server_fd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Ascolto del socket
    if (listen(server_fd, 10) == -1) {
        perror("Errore nella listen");
        close(server_fd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
        
        if(server_fd>max_fd) max_fd = server_fd;
        
    // Inizializza i descrittori
    FD_ZERO(&active_fds);
    FD_SET(server_fd, &active_fds);
    
    while (1) {
      read_fds = active_fds;

      // Monitora i descrittori con la select
      if (select(max_fd + 1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
          perror("Errore in select");
          break;
      }
            
            for(fd = 0; fd<=max_fd; fd++){
                if(FD_ISSET(fd, &read_fds)){
                    if(fd == server_fd){
                        client_fd = accept(server_fd, NULL, 0);
                        FD_SET(client_fd, &active_fds);
                        if(client_fd>max_fd) max_fd = client_fd;
                    }else{
                        if((nread = read(fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE)) == 0){
                            FD_CLR(fd, &active_fds);
                            max_fd = aggiorna(&active_fds);
                            close(fd);
                        }else{
                            printf("%s\n", buffer);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }

    close(server_fd);
    unlink(SOCKET_PATH);

    return 0;
}

For each client that I try to connect I get the error "Errore nella connessione al server" that means "Can't connect to the server" when they execute the connect function.
Let me know if you need more information to understand, thanks.
EDIT: Here is the implementation of the socket server that I used to fix the code, it's the same in both client and server.
    struct sockaddr_un server_addr;
    
    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(server_addr.sun_path, SOCKET_PATH,sizeof(server_addr.sun_path) - 1);


In the client, you need to show us how you set up server_addr. It would also be useful if, in the client, you used perror to report what the error that caused the failure was.

Thanks, I fixed it. When I read your comment I understood that I had to set up server_addr in the client as well. My professor only showed server initialization and I thought it was shared between client and server. Now it works.

I suggest to [edit] the question and show a [mre] to allows us to try and reproduce the problem.

Please also format your code consistently. Many IDEs have tools for that built in, use it.

Rather than put the answer in the question, you should make an answer (yes, you can answer your own questions) And then accept that answer (you may have to wait half an hour before accepting it). That way everybody knows your problem is fixed and other people with the same problem can find your answer easily.
